# ListBox vs. ListView - how to choose for data binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listview, listbox

I'm considering either a ListBox or a ListView for a WPF application.  It seems either supports data binding and item templates.  My application has a simple list of items that I intend to be able to search/sort/filter based on user input.  The data binding demo (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771319.aspx) uses a ListBox with a CollectionViewSource.

Does anyone have pros/cons for which control to use and when?

Answer (score 376, accepted):

A `ListView` is a specialized `ListBox` (that is, it inherits from `ListBox`).  It allows you to specify different views rather than a straight list. You can either roll your own view, or use `GridView` (think Explorer-like "details view"). It's basically the multi-column `ListBox`, the cousin of Windows Forms' `ListView`.

If you don't need the additional capabilities of `ListView`, you can certainly use `ListBox` if you're simply showing a list of items (Even if the template is complex).

Comment: What's the difference between that and `DataGrid`? Unless `ListView` enables you to change the view dynamically (like win-explorer - list, details, large icons), I don't see why using it...