# How do I bind a Listview SelectedItem to a Textbox using the TwoWay mode?

Tags: wpf, listview, 2-way-object-databinding

I am very new to WPF and testing some things that I would like to include in an application that I will be working on. I have a 2 row ListView (bound to a textbox) with the names Scott Guthrie and Jon Skeet in it. I am trying to select "Scott Guthrie" in the ListView and have it populate the TextBox. I want to be able to edit the text and tab off and have the ListView updated.

**Edit**:I removed the code since that really didn't add anything to the question.

Comment: that's too much information :) just for next time

Comment: share your code, plz. @Nick U.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Wow, that's really complicated what you've got there.

This can be accomplished in a very simple way.  You need a model to represent the programmer, a view model to hold a list of programmers, and simple binding to take care of the rest.

The model:

```
public sealed class Programmer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Its very simple.  An object representing a programmer with a name.  We must encapsulate the name within an object because strings are immutable in .NET.  If you tried binding against a single string in a list of strings, changes wouldn't propagate.

The collection of programmers is kept in a ViewModel.  In this case, I call it ViewModel, because I have no imagination.  This view model contains everything that the view binds against.  In this case, its the list of programmers.

```
public sealed class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Programmer> Programmers { get; private set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Programmers = new ObservableCollection<Programmer>();
    }
}
```

The ViewModel is set as the DataContext of our view.  The DataContext flows down the visual tree, and we can bind against it at any point.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    var vm = new ViewModel();
    vm.Programmers.Add(new Programmer { Name = "Jon Skeet" });
    vm.Programmers.Add(new Programmer { Name = "Scott Guthrie" });
    DataContext = vm;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

You can set the DataContext in any way you want; I'm doing it here for simplicity's sake.

In the UI, I simply bind the ListView against the list of Programmers in the ViewModel (the DataContext, unless otherwise stated, is the root of the binding path).  I then bind the TextBox against the SelectedItem of the ListBox.  You select a Programmer from the list, which then becomes the SelectedItem, which I can then change the Name of.

```
<Window
    x:Class="Programmers.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:t="clr-namespace:Programmers"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox
            x:Name="list"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Programmers}"
            DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
        <TextBox
            Grid.Column="1"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Name, ElementName=list}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Simple, once you get the hang of it.

Comment: Yeah, seems like knowing is half the battle. Thanks! That did it!

Comment: @nick GI Joooooeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee!

Comment: +1. Thanks man, it really helped me! I used `list.ItemSource = vm` instead of `DataContext = vm` though. I think I have too when I have multiple list, but not sure because I'm new to WPF.

Comment: Tiny note, since the OP asked about `ListView` and this solution is for `ListBox`: [`ListView` is a subclass of `ListBox`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/227355/1174169), so this code works fine for either.

Answer (score 5):

This works (except that you need to validate the textbox since you can enter any text.. a dropdown might be a better choice).

View:

```
<TabItem x:Name="RightTabPage" Header="RightModel"  DataContext="{Binding Right}">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedGuru}"/>
                        <ListView SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGuru}" ItemsSource="{Binding Gurus}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </TabItem>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class RightViewModel
    {
        public RightViewModel()
        {
            Gurus = new[] {"Scott Guthrie", "Jon Skeet"};
            SelectedGuru = Gurus.First();
        }

        public string SelectedGuru { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> Gurus{ get; set; }
    }
```