# Filling a ListBox from two TextBoxes with DataBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, listbox

I have a `ListBox` I want to fill with data from two `TextBoxes`by clicking a Button. I think the problem comes from the differents `textblock` i have in my `listbox`. Here is what i want in image :
 [TheUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASymq.png)
The `MainWindow.xaml` of my `listbox` :

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Issues}"  Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="366" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="453" Margin="0,0,-1,0">
        <StackPanel Margin="3">
            <DockPanel >
                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Issue:"
              DockPanel.Dock="Left"
              Margin="5,0,10,0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="  " />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Issue}"  Foreground="Green" FontWeight="Bold" />
            </DockPanel>
            <DockPanel >
                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Comment:" Foreground ="DarkOrange"
              DockPanel.Dock="Left"
              Margin="5,0,5,0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Comment}" />

            </DockPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </ListBox>
```

My `MainWindow.xaml.cs`

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    public sealed class ViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Issue> Issues { get; private set; }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            Issues = new ObservableCollection<Issue>();
        }
    }

    private void addIssue_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var vm = new ViewModel();
        vm.Issues.Add(new Issue { Name = "Jon Skeet", Comment = "lolilol" });
        DataContext = vm;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

My `Issue.cs` :

```
public sealed class Issue
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

I follow this tutorial but i don't want to implement a Database : 
[Tuto](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/listbox-in-wpf/)
I also try to use this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529242/how-do-i-bind-a-listview-selecteditem-to-a-textbox-using-the-twoway-mode.)
The error i have is `'System.InvalidOperationException'` `The Items collection must be empty to use ItemsSource`
But not sure this is the heart of the problem.

Comment: Why are you setting your datacontext on each button click?

Comment: Because i want to add a pair of Issue/Comment each time i press the button

Comment: You don't need to do that. ObservableCollection takes care of updating the UI each time a new Issue is added

Comment: Even if i want the UI to update only when i press the button ?

Comment: Yes, because is only when you press the button when you are adding a new object to your ObservableCollection. Anyway, try changing in your Listbox the textblock bindings from  `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Issue}"` to `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Issue}"` once you have your code as @HariPrasad told you in his answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove whatever you have inserted between `<ListBox> and </ListBox>`, as it is treated as part of `Items` collection.

Instead shift that content between `<ListBox.ItemTemplate>...</ListBox.ItemTemplate>`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to update `Context` and `InitializeComponent` every time, atleast to your case.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = vm;
    }


    public sealed class ViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Issue> Issues { get; private set; }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            Issues = new ObservableCollection<Issue>();
        }
    }

    private void addIssue_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {       
        vm.Issues.Add(new Issue { Name = "Jon Skeet", Comment = "lolilol" });       
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't have the error anymore but this does not add anything to the `Listbox` :/

EDIT : Well my bad i have the same error and this does not open the window anymore