# ListView vs ListBox performance

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, listbox

So I have been dealing with a problem representing 10k+ rows in a listview (I might need pagination, but this is not about that), I had 2 problems:

1. Item source loading took at least 10 seconds to load into the listview which made my UI hang
2. Lag while focusing the listview

So I wanted to compare the same thing using a listbox than a datagrid. And I was amazed how the listbox reduced the loading time to almost nothing and also there is no lag.

Listview:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SymbolContext}" BorderThickness="0">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>                                      
            <VirtualizingStackPanel />                                      
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

ListBox:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SymbolContext}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>                                       
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

So my question is why did it take for the listview so much to represent the data and why did the listbox perform so well?

Comment: Have you used a profiler? Will surely show you why some code is slower or faster than another one.

Comment: Please look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703641/what-is-the-difference-between-listbox-and-listview and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227231/listbox-vs-listview-how-to-choose-for-data-binding

Comment: I have read the 2 article but still there shouldn't be such a huge performance difference between the controls.